# How to Generate JWT secrets

Tags: jwt

I have been following Taiseer Joudeh's tutorial on using Asp.Net Web Api, specifically the following [link](http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/), but in step 3 he suggests to make entries for as:AudienceId and as;AudienceSecret in appSettins section of web.config. He suggests generating the keys by following [this](https://github.com/tjoudeh/JWTAspNetWebApi/blob/master/AuthorizationServer.Api/AudiencesStore.cs#l24-34) but I can't see how the code pointed to by the link can be used to generate keys.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The clientId is a unique value and generated by `Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")`. It does not have to be a GUID at all, indeed.

And the secret is created also in a rather arbitrary way (*RNG* in RNGCryptoServiceProvider stands for 'Random Number Generator')

The crucial thing is not to generate them at all, but to keep on the resource server as it is. Your authorization server should be able to generate them for your needs once you even copy-paste that sample code in your app.